# Flask: Keep last selected item in drop downs (Jinja)

Tags: python, flask

i selected a country from a screener function, send this form again to screener function
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFlyK.png)
The problem, my form don't keep the last selected country in my form (the variable "country" is send ). I always have the value 'Any' in the form

my list for select
example i
id=1 => 'France'
id=2 => 'Japan'...  so if a choose Japan, (id=2) [2]i want to see Japan  and not "Any" in the form
[enter image description here]

your help would be appreciated
thank you

screener.html

```
<form method=POST action="{{ url_for('screener') }}" onchange=submit()>
  <table class="table table-sm table-hover">
    <thead>
    <tr><td>control : {{ country }}</td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Country</td>
        <td>
          <select id="country" name="country" class="form-select form-select-sm" aria-label="">
            <option value="">Any</option>
            {% for db_country in db_countries %}
              <option value="{{ db_country.id }}" {% if country == db_country.id %} selected {% endif %} >
                {{ db_country.id }} - {{ db_country.name }}`</option>
            {% endfor %}
          </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

app.py

```
`@app.route('/screener/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def screener():
    db_countries = Country.query.order_by(Country.name.asc()).all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        country = request.form['country']
    else:
        country = 0
    return render_template('screener.html', title='Screener',db_countries=db_countries, country=country)`
```

Comment: Add `selected` into the `option` tag if the passed `id` matches that of the option. You can pop an in-line `if` statement into the `option` to perform this test.

Comment: i already do that but i always have the problem (don't keep last selected)
<option value="{{ db_country.id }}" {% if country == db_country.id %} selected {% endif %} >{{ db_country.id }} - {{ db_country.name }}`</option>

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing a `str` to an `int`. For this reason, the comparison fails.
Change the variable `country` to an `int` and it works.

Either you change the type in the endpoint

```py
country = request.form.get('country', 0, type=int)
```

or in the template.

```html
{% if country | int == db_country.id %} selected {% endif %}
```

Comment: all is ok now!  Thank you very much